# Change WordPress exit address

Tags: php, wordpress, url, exit

**I want to change the exit address of WordPress. Or if I can create an exit address.**

For example, the wordpress exit address:

test.zhk/wp-login.php?action=logout

Favorite Address:

**test.zhk/user/logout**

I created this address with RewriteRule WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

if you want do it when the user log out can use this hook wp_logout

like this

```
do_action( 'wp_logout', 'your_function' )
```

or need specialize for yourself can make hook for your function by

```
add_action  see
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/